# How can I install Bluetooth drivers on a Lenovo G470?

Tags: 12.10, bluetooth, lenovo

I'm having problems with my Bluetooth.
I have 12.10 installed in my Lenovo G470.
I have already tried installing Blueman & Additional Drivers, but it is still not working.
Below is the sudo rfkill list

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Try pairing the device first. Also try pairing from the phone/other device.

Comment: I tried pairing with my handphone. I can switched on the Bluetooth, but couldn't switch on the 'Visibility' and it still says the 'Bluetooth is disabled'

Answer (score 0):

I know is is working because I used it before , may a reboot on win help to switch it on ?

-- 
http://rzr.online.fr/q/bluetooth